# Activities overview hotkey customisation

Tags: shortcut-keys, customization, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I've been using Activities Overview to navigate between windows, because I like being able to see the windows in 2D (as opposed to the list form of <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>, which I often need to press many times to get to the window I want).

The <kbd>Up</kbd>, <kbd>Down</kbd>, <kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Right</kbd> keys currently move between windows, but I'd like to use <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>L</kbd> instead. Currently these keys type a search entry, but I don't use the search function much anyway.

Is there a way I can configure this setup? Alternatively, is there an easier way to change between many windows other than pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> lots of times?

Answer (score 0):

You may use a [GNOME extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called "[windowNavigator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/10/windownavigator/)". This extension does

> Allow keyboard selection of windows and workspaces in overlay mode.

Once you have installed and activated the extension (you may have to re-login once) press <kbd>Super</kbd> to get to Activities overview. Then press and hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>. A unique number will appear over each window (see screenshot below). Press the number corresponding to the window you want to switch to while still holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

[image]

Unfortunately, you can use this feature for up to 9 windows per workspace (can't press two-digit numbers).